# How to execute inference of tensorflow model in Android

Tags: android, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow-lite

I tried use Tensorflow Lite, but it has lots of limitations, it doesn't have batch normalization operation, and even with simple operations it gave a very strange result to the same data tested with Keras. It means with keras everything works, with tensorflow lite, the result is completely wrong. So I need something to execute the .pb file on Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `TensorFlowInferenceInterface` to make predictions using a .pb file. First, place the .pb file in your app's assets folder.

1. In your build.gradle(Module: app) file, add the following dependency,
   `implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:1.11.0'`
2. Then initialize TensorFlowInferenceInterface, if your model files name is "model.pb" then , 
   `TensorFlowInferenceInterface tensorFlowInferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(context.getAssets() , "file:///android_asset/model.pb") ;`
3. `tensorFlowInferenceInterface.feed( INPUT_NAME , inputs , 1, 28, 28);` where `INPUT_NAME` is the name of your input layer. `1 , 50` are the input dimensions.
4. `tensorFlowInferenceInterface.run( new String[]{ OUTPUT_NAME } );` where `OUTPUT_NAME` is the name of your output layer.
5. `float[] outputs = new float[ nuymber_of_classes ];
     tensorFlowInferenceInterface.fetch( OUTPUT_NAME , outputs ) ;`

`outputs` are the float values which are predicted from your model.

Here's the full code :

```
TensorFlowInferenceInterface tensorFlowInferenceInterface = new 
TensorFlowInferenceInterface(context.getAssets() , "file:///android_asset/model.pb");
tensorFlowInferenceInterface.feed( INPUT_NAME , inputs , 1, 28, 28);
tensorFlowInferenceInterface.run( new String[]{ OUTPUT_NAME } );
float[] outputs = new float[ nuymber_of_classes ];
tensorFlowInferenceInterface.fetch( OUTPUT_NAME , outputs ) ;
```